# Custom metadata of .NET assembly

Tags: .net, metadata, .net-assembly

I am creating an architecture where we use a lot of plugins. We'd like to implement sort of "assembly custom metadata", which would tell the plugin host required settings for this assembly. We'd like to "describe" those settings in xml and include that xml description inside the assembly. Is it feasible? I know that I can use a custom assembly attribute, but I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on why custom assembly (and type) attributes aren't a good solution for your scenario. Attributes are simple to use and fast. Why don't you want to use them?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that.

1. You can require plugin authors to embed a resource with a well-defined name, like `PluginDescriptor.xml`, into the assembly and then `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` it in your host application
2. Or you can define an assembly-leve `PluginDescriptorAttribute`, which would contain the name of the resource to read to get hold of the XML file
3. Or you can redistribute the file alongside with the DLL (or pack them up into a ZIP file, much like `nupkg` files are packaged)